# django.setup() in every python test file needed?

Tags: python, django

I execute one particular test via PyCharm (ctrl-shift-F10).

I get this error:

```
Testing started at 18:12 ...
/home/guettli/simple21env/bin/python /snap/pycharm-community/188/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pycharm/_jb_unittest_runner.py --target simple21.tests.TermTests.test_str_of_sub_term
Launching unittests with arguments python -m unittest simple21.tests.TermTests.test_str_of_sub_term in /home/guettli/simple21env/src/simple21tree

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/snap/pycharm-community/188/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pycharm/_jb_unittest_runner.py", line 35, in <module>
    main(argv=args, module=None, testRunner=unittestpy.TeamcityTestRunner, buffer=not JB_DISABLE_BUFFERING)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/unittest/main.py", line 94, in __init__
    self.parseArgs(argv)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/unittest/main.py", line 141, in parseArgs
    self.createTests()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/unittest/main.py", line 148, in createTests
    self.module)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/unittest/loader.py", line 219, in loadTestsFromNames
    suites = [self.loadTestsFromName(name, module) for name in names]
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/unittest/loader.py", line 219, in <listcomp>
    suites = [self.loadTestsFromName(name, module) for name in names]
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/unittest/loader.py", line 153, in loadTestsFromName
    module = __import__(module_name)
  File "/home/guettli/simple21env/src/simple21tree/simple21/tests.py", line 7, in <module>
    from . import views
  File "/home/guettli/simple21env/src/simple21tree/simple21/views.py", line 5, in <module>
    from simple21.models import Term, SearchLog, GlobalConfig
  File "/home/guettli/simple21env/src/simple21tree/simple21/models.py", line 1, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
  File "/home/guettli/simple21env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "/home/guettli/simple21env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 47, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "/home/guettli/simple21env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 107, in __new__
    app_config = apps.get_containing_app_config(module)
  File "/home/guettli/simple21env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 252, in get_containing_app_config
    self.check_apps_ready()
  File "/home/guettli/simple21env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 135, in check_apps_ready
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.

Process finished with exit code 1

Empty suite
```

I guess I need to call [django.setup()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/settings/#calling-django-setup-is-required-for-standalone-django-usage).

Is there no way to avoid writing `django.setup()` in every python test file?

Running the test from the command line works. This question is about calling one particular test directly from PyCharm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched to [pytest-django](https://pytest-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

If you configure the `pytest.ini` like this, it works fine:

```
[pytest]
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE = mysite.settings
```

The exception "django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet." is gone now.

Answer (score 1):

For test cases, you really only need to import `from django.test import TestCase`
You should not need to run `.setup()`

Here is a minimal test script

```
from django.test import TestCase

class UnitTestCase(TestCase):

    def test_home_homepage_template(self):
        response = self.client.get('/')
        self.assertTemplateUsed(response, 'my_app/home.html')
```

If you run `python manage.py test` do you get the same error?  Are you writing tests in `app_name/tests.py`?

Comment: Running the test from the command line works. This question is about calling one particular test directly from PyCharm.

Comment: OK, in PyCharm you can open up the `tests.py` and on the left column where the line numbers are, there should be a play button by each test.  You can click on each one of those to run individual tests.  Here is a screenshot https://imgur.com/a/fDXUdn4